# How to change border Color of thumb of switch react core component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, switch-statement, components

[image]on pressing the thumb of switch of react native its giving me default color in place of thumb color border should be of nearby to orange how to eliminate it? and substitute the color

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { Switch, View } from 'react-native';
import { useTheme } from 'react-native-paper';

interface IMSwitchProps {
  toggleValue: boolean;
  onToggleChange: (value?: any) => void;
  disableSwitch?: boolean;
  testId?: string;
}

const IMSwitch: FunctionComponent<IMSwitchProps> = (props: IMSwitchProps) => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <View>
      <Switch
        value={props.toggleValue}
        onValueChange={(value) => {
          props.onToggleChange(value);
        }}
        trackColor={{
          false: props.disableSwitch ? theme.Palette.grey[100] : theme.Palette.grey[500],
          true: props.disableSwitch ? theme.Palette.grey[100] : theme.Palette.IMPrimary.border,
        }}
        thumbColor={
          props.disableSwitch
            ? theme.Palette.background
            : props.toggleValue
            ? theme.Palette.IMPrimary.main
            : theme.Palette.background
        }
        disabled={props.disableSwitch}
        testID={props.testId}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
export default IMSwitch;
```

tried by giving style to switch